# select item from table and order by amount on 2 days?

Tags: mysql

For example I have below table:

```
 ---------------------
|  amount |   date    |
 ---------------------
|  50     |   Day 1   |
|  60     |   day 2   |
|  20     |   day 3   |
|  25     |   day 3   |
|  23     |   day 4   |
|  26     |   day 4   |
|  15     |   day 5   |
 ---------------------
```

What I basically want to do is to retrieve item from last 2 days and order the row by max amount. so the result would be like:

```
 ---------------------
|  amount |   date    |
 ---------------------
|  26     |   day 4   |
|  23     |   day 4   |
|  15     |   day 5   |
 ---------------------
```

FYI: the date input is in `2018-06-10 14:37:44` mode above is just an example

I tried: `SELECT AMOUNT FROM table WHERE AMOUNT=(SELECT MAX(AMOUNT) FROM table) ORDER BY DATE;`

But the result I am getting is only `|  60     |   day 2   |` which is the max amount and is not from 2 recent dates;

Comment: What is the key in this table?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Niver the key is the amount

Comment: @Temmpo It doesn't make much of a sencse to have a quantity as an id of a table. It seems that you should have an item id here.

Comment: @Niver Obviously there is more columns in my real tables, But i tried to keep my example as precise as I can, I simply want to order rows by max amount from day 4 and 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function that gives you a date after a certain time alongside [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) that gives you current date;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT amount, date FROM table WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) ORDER BY amount DESC;

-- date > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) will give you all rows within 2 days
-- ORDER BY amount DESC will give you ordered by amount descending
```

Comment: That is not really gonna work. because everyday I have to update my query, I need an automatic way of doing the same thing

Comment: I have made it generic